# acts_as_taggable_on finding tags of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

In my Rails app, I have a model called **Projects** and projects have man **Spins**.  I'm using the gem [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) to enable users to add tags to their Spins.

I'd like to be able to filter projects by tags, so if a project has any spin that contains the particular tag, I'd like to return that project in search results.

I know that I can search for Spins that have particular tags with the following:

```
Spin.tagged_with("LEGO")
```

How can I do an associated search, something like

```
Project.find(1).spins.where(:tagged_with => "LEGO")
```

(this doesn't work because there is no tagged_with attribute of Spins – acts_as_taggable_on adds a separate table for tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Project.joins(:spins).where('spins.id IN (?)', Spin.tagged_with("LEGO").select(:id))
```